# Laptop shows the same error regardless of booting option

Tags: windows-8, boot, bsod, lenovo-laptop

PROBLEM:

The laptop does boot but reaches the infamous blue screen with the text that says "Your PC ran into a problem :("

After the blue screen the window goes black with the Windows logo and a text at the bottom that says "Preparing automatic repair". After displaying that for 1 minute the screen goes completely black.

Around 15-20 mins later the logo reappears and the text now says "Diagnosing PC" which stays for around 10 mins.

And finally a new text appears that says "Repairing disk errors. This might take over an hour to complete". This appears for about 5 minutes and then the laptop promptly displays "Preparing automatic repair" again and goes through the steps again in a loop without end.

I have tried system restore but the same thing described above happened after clicking it. So that seems out of the question and now I have no idea what to do.

WHAT DOES WORK:

I can access the BIOS menu and also Boot menu, so it's not completely gone.

WHAT I CANNOT DO AT THE MOMENT BUT WILL TRY LATER:

- Insert a bootable USB/DVD with Windows OS and boot through that.
- Insert the HDD into another laptop to check if it's at fault.

SPECS:

Lenovo G500S Laptop
Windows 8.1

WHAT HAPPENED:

I honestly don't know. I was playing The Walking Dead Season 2 and then needed to leave so I left the laptop hibernating and did not close the game (Alt+tab'd out). When I came back the game was very sluggish so I decided to restart and then the problem began.

Managed to capture a snapshot of the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick search generated this link:

http://www.deskdecode.com/how-to-fix-bsod-unmountable-boot-volume-stop-0x000000ed/

This will probably help with what you are trying to do. Until you have a chance to do what you said:

> WHAT I CANNOT DO AT THE MOMENT BUT WILL TRY LATER:
>
> Insert a bootable USB/DVD with Windows OS and boot through that.
>   Insert the HDD into another laptop to check if it's at fault.

I am not sure if anything else can help at the moment.